# Get raw email message in java

Tags: java, email

I want to get the raw message from an email. Like if I use show original on gmail or show source message in thunderbird.

Like:

```
Delivered-To: bla@gmail.com
Received: by 10.107.155.149 with SMTP id d143csp535445ioe;
        Sun, 19 Jul 2015 00:10:40 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.180.23.33 with SMTP id j1mr10065676wif.44.1437289839737;
        Sun, 19 Jul 2015 00:10:39 -0700 (PDT)
```

My code so far:

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
    try {
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
        Store store = session.getStore();
        store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "xxx@gmail.com", "xxx");
        Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
        inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
        Message msg = inbox.getMessage(inbox.getMessageCount());


    } catch (Exception mex) {
        mex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

So how to I get the source code of the email from msg?

Best regards,
Peter